# JavaScript - passing a variable to div

Tags: innerhtml

Have a quick question:

How do you pass a variable into a  tag in an HTML file that is the result of a return statement in a JS function? For example:

```
function myFunction(var1){

var result = "";

<-------code and loop here-------->

return result;
}


var answer = myFunction(234);
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = answer;
```

The Div in my html file is assumed to be myDiv. However, I can't get that variable result into that Div. It simply doesn't show up when I render it. I know that the Div is there and works, I can hard code text into it.....

I've been playing with this for what seems like an age now....and it's frustrating to say the least. I just KNOW this is something simple that I am not seeing.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the element is on the page before the script runs?

Try (in order of least to most preferable):

- Moving the script to the end of the `<body>` element (right before `</body>`)
- Using `window.onload`
- Implementing a "queue" system that runs the functions when the page is ready

Comment: I guess I don't exactly know how to answer the order question. I have the script src tag in the head of the html. I assume that means that the JS runs before the div is made?

Comment: That is correct. If you looked at your browser's console, you'd have been able to figure it out.